# dynamic check/uncheck of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, oracle-apex

There are plenty posts about checking/unchecking checkboxes dynamically but I suppose my is a little bit diferent.
My checkbox is mulitple values checkbox (I use it to parametrize graph) where data comes from query somthing like:

```
select 'all' as val from dual
union
select name_of_month as val from months
```

So the result is 13 checkboxes : [0] (all)  [1]-[12] (jan feb mar etc.)

What I would like to get is below behaviours

- when I check (all)  all 13 checkboxes will check
- when I uncheck (all)  all 13 checkboxes will uncheck
- when I uncheck one of 1-12 checkboxes and (all) is checked  will uncheck
- when all 12 checkboxes are checked one by one checkbox will also be checked

I am not sure if description above is clear enough but I believe You feel how this checkbox should work

UPDATE:
I am Oracle DBA (with basic knowledge of JavaScript) who try to create something in APEX. Until I use wizzards and mouse to draw objects it is easy.  Right now I see I have to type a few lines of code so please give me at least some explanation where to type it and how to run it to let it work.

Comment: Are you using jQuery in your project? or you just want to achieve this with vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: I don't know how are you creating these checkboxes, but if they are items. Using the Jakir solution you need to create a dynamic action on page load with that javascript. And then, go to your "ALL" checkbox and in the field Custom Attributes put >>> class="all_chkbox" <<< and in each item put  >>> class="chkbox" <<< example: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=145797:1

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this using jquery. I made a sample code for your project. Hope it will help.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.all_chkbox').change(function(){
        if($(this)[0].checked){
            $('.chkbox').prop("checked", true);
        }else{

            $('.chkbox').prop("checked", false);
        }
    });

    $('.chkbox').change(function(){
        var flag = true;
        $('.chkbox').each(function(){
            if(!$(this)[0].checked){
                flag = false;
                return;
            }
        });
        $('.all_chkbox').prop("checked", flag);
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Checkbox</title>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="checkbox_wrapper">
        <input class="all_chkbox" type="checkbox">
        <ul>
            <li>checkbox 1 <input class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="" ></li>
            <li>checkbox 2 <input class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="" ></li>
            <li>checkbox 3 <input class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="" ></li>
            <li>checkbox 4 <input class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="" ></li>
            <li>checkbox 5 <input class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="" ></li>
            <li>checkbox 6 <input class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="" ></li>
            <li>checkbox 7 <input class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="" ></li>
            <li>checkbox 8 <input class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="" ></li>
            <li>checkbox 9 <input class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="" ></li>
            <li>checkbox 10 <input class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="" ></li>
            <li>checkbox 11 <input class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="" ></li>
            <li>checkbox 12 <input class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="" ></li>
            <li>checkbox 13 <input class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="" ></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in my React project scenario is little different but possibly this will help you out .....

So this is my checkbox element which you can replicate as per your needs :

```
<input type="checkbox" checked={this.isChecked(props.original.EmployeeId)} onChange={this.singleChange.bind(this, props.original.EmployeeId)}

isChecked = (empId) => {
        let checkedItems = this.state.checkItems;
        return checkedItems.indexOf(empId) > -1;
    }



 singleChange = (employeeId, event) => {
            let checkedItems = this.state.checkItems;
            if (event.target.checked) {
                checkedItems.push(employeeId);
            }
            else {
                if (checkedItems.includes(employeeId)) {
                    let index = checkedItems.indexOf(employeeId);
                    checkedItems.splice(index, 1);
                }
            }
            checkedItems.length == this.props.employees.length ? this.setState({ allChecked: true }) : this.setState({ allChecked: false })
            this.setState({ checkItems: checkedItems })    
        }
```

Here, I am maintaining an array which contains employeeId of those employees whom I'll be checking, therefore isChecked is a function which checks that the employee is checked or relatively you can say that the checkbox is checked or not.
singleChange() function is called at the time of onChange event which is only for inserting and removing id from array if checked or un-checked respectively.
But according to your scenario here the second the last line of code is important which checks if all are checked or not. So, if uou'll uncheck one all checkbox will be un-checked, if you'll check one by one all checkboxes then (all) checkbox will be checked automatically. For (all) one checkbox you'll have to maintain a boolean variable.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.allChecked} onChange={this.allChecked}></input> 

allChecked = (event) => {
        const allEmployeeIds = this.props.employees.map(employee => employee.EmployeeId);
        if (event.target.checked) {
            this.setState({ checkItems: allEmployeeIds });
            this.setState({ allChecked: true })
        }
        else {
            this.setState({ checkItems: [] });
            this.setState({ allChecked: false });
        }
    }
```

This above input element is my select all checkbox. It gets checked on the basis of boolean variable all checked. Here allChecked function is called when onChange event gets fired. If checked this function will put all id's in the same array used above and if unchecked array will be made empty.

Don't get confused with state and other properties as I have done this in react. This will possibly help you out. Feel free to ask, if stucked